# While loop wont end

Tags: php, while-loop

I am running a text based game and trying to get a function to repeat itself using a while loop but when the condition is met it wont stop.

```
<?php
/****************************************************************/
/*********************** Created By Seker ***********************/
/**** Feel free to modify in any way, but keep this section. ****/
/****************************************************************/
session_start();
require "global_func.php";
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == 0)
{
header("Location: login.php");
exit;
}
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
require "header.php";
$h = new headers;
$h->startheaders();
include "mysql.php";
global $c;
$is =
    mysql_query(
            "SELECT u.*,us.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN userstats us ON u.userid=us.userid WHERE u.userid=$userid",
            $c) or die(mysql_error());
$ir = mysql_fetch_array($is);
check_level();
$fm = money_formatter($ir['money']);
$cm = money_formatter($ir['crystals'], '');
$lv = date('F j, Y, g:i a', $ir['laston']);
$h->userdata($ir, $lv, $fm, $cm);
$h->menuarea();

switch ($_GET['action'])
{
case 'walk':
walk();
break;

case 'walk2':
 walk();
 break;

default:
home();
break;
}

function home()
{


global $ir,$h,$c,$userid;

$q=mysql_query("SELECT u.*,c.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN cities c ON u.location=c.cityid WHERE u.userid=$userid");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($q);

$city = $r['cityname'];
$trav = $ir['steps'];

echo "
    <table width='70%' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                <font size='3'><b><u>The $city Streets</u></b></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                Take your chances with a walk through the $city streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                Each day, you get <b>10</b> steps! <b>25</b> if you are a donator!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                While traveling, you can find crystals, cash, or even gain experience!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center'>
                But, be careful! There are dangers in the streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
";

echo "
    <table width='70%' border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                <font size='3'><b><u>What would you like to do?</u></b></font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                You can travel <b>{$trav}</b> more times today!
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'>[Go For A Walk]</a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='index.php'>[Change Your Mind]</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
";
}



function walk()
{
do
{


global $ir,$h,$c,$userid;

$q=mysql_query("SELECT u.*,c.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN cities c ON u.location=c.cityid WHERE u.userid=$userid");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($q);

$chance = mt_rand(1,100);
$city = $r['cityname'];
$trav = $ir['steps'];

if ($ir['steps'] <= 0)
{
    echo "
        You have traveled enough for today! Come back tomorrow!
        <a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
        exit($h->endpage());
}

if ($ir['hospital'])
{
    echo "
        You cannot travel while in the hospital!
        <a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
        exit($h->endpage());
}

if ($ir['jail'])
{
    echo "
        You cannot travel while in jail!
        <a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
        exit($h->endpage());
}


echo "
    <table width=70% border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <font size='2'>You start your journey through the $city streets!</font>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <font size='2'>You can travel up to <b>{$trav}</b> more times today!</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>";

if ($chance <= 10)
{
    $rewardtok = mt_rand(5,15);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET crystals=crystals+$rewardtok,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

    echo "
                <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                    Congratulations! You found <b>$rewardtok</b> crystals while walking through the streets!
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
                </td>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
}

if (($chance >= 15) && ($chance <= 30))
{
    $rewardg = mt_rand(100,5000);
    $reward = money_formatter($rewardg);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+$rewardg,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

    echo "
                <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                    Congratulations! You found <b>$reward</b> while walking through the streets!
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
                </td>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
}


if (($chance >= 40) && ($chance <= 50))
{
    $rewardexp = mt_rand(5,50) * ($ir['level'] /2);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET exp=exp+$rewardexp,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

    echo "
                <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                    Congratulations! You gained <b>$rewardexp<b> experience while walking through the streets!
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
                </td>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
}

if (($chance >= 55) && ($chance <= 65))
{
    $rewardexp = mt_rand(5,50);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET exp=exp+$rewardexp,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

    echo "
                <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                    Congratulations! You gained <b>$rewardexp<b> experience while walking through the streets!
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
                </td>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
        }

 if (($chance >= 75) && ($chance <= 85))
    {
     $rewardtok = mt_rand(5,15);

    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET crystals=crystals+$rewardtok,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

    echo "
                <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                    Congratulations! You found <b>$rewardtok</b> crystals while walking through the streets!
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
                </td>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
 }
if ((($chance > 10) && ($chance < 15)) || (($chance > 30) && ($chance < 40)) || (($chance > 50) && ($chance < 55)) || (($chance > 65) && ($chance < 75)) || ($chance > 85))
{
     $rewardtok = mt_rand(5,15);
      mysql_query("UPDATE users SET steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

    echo "
                <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                    You found nothing while walking through the streets
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
                </td>
                <td align='center' width='50%'>
                    <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";


  }

 }
while ($ir['steps'] > 0);
}
$h->endpage();
```

The function is supposed to run until the steps value is 0 which when the function runs once it subtracts from the total. yet it doesnt stop when it hits 0 and i get something like this "Steps: -15535"

i believe this is the "relivent code"

```
function walk()
{
do
{


global $ir,$h,$c,$userid;

$q=mysql_query("SELECT u.*,c.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN cities c ON u.location=c.cityid WHERE u.userid=$userid");
$r=mysql_fetch_array($q);

$chance = mt_rand(1,100);
$city = $r['cityname'];
$trav = $ir['steps'];

if ($ir['steps'] <= 0)
{
echo "
    You have traveled enough for today! Come back tomorrow!
    <a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
    exit($h->endpage());
}

if ($ir['hospital'])
{
echo "
    You cannot travel while in the hospital!
    <a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
    exit($h->endpage());
}

if ($ir['jail'])
{
echo "
    You cannot travel while in jail!
    <a href='index.php'>Home</a>";
    exit($h->endpage());
}


echo "
<table width=70% border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td align='center' width='50%'>
            <font size='2'>You start your journey through the $city streets!</font>
        </td>
        <td align='center' width='50%'>
            <font size='2'>You can travel up to <b>{$trav}</b> more times today!</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>";

if ($chance <= 10)
{
$rewardtok = mt_rand(5,15);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET crystals=crystals+$rewardtok,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

echo "
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                Congratulations! You found <b>$rewardtok</b> crystals while walking through the streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
}

if (($chance >= 15) && ($chance <= 30))
{
$rewardg = mt_rand(100,5000);
$reward = money_formatter($rewardg);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+$rewardg,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

echo "
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                Congratulations! You found <b>$reward</b> while walking through the streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
}


if (($chance >= 40) && ($chance <= 50))
{
$rewardexp = mt_rand(5,50) * ($ir['level'] /2);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET exp=exp+$rewardexp,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

echo "
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                Congratulations! You gained <b>$rewardexp<b> experience while walking through the streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
}

if (($chance >= 55) && ($chance <= 65))
{
$rewardexp = mt_rand(5,50);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET exp=exp+$rewardexp,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

echo "
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                Congratulations! You gained <b>$rewardexp<b> experience while walking through the streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
    }

 if (($chance >= 75) && ($chance <= 85))
{
 $rewardtok = mt_rand(5,15);

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET crystals=crystals+$rewardtok,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

echo "
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                Congratulations! You found <b>$rewardtok</b> crystals while walking through the streets!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
 }
if ((($chance > 10) && ($chance < 15)) || (($chance > 30) && ($chance < 40)) || (($chance > 50) && ($chance < 55)) || (($chance > 65) && ($chance < 75)) || ($chance > 85))
{
 $rewardtok = mt_rand(5,15);
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

echo "
            <td align='center' colspan='2'>
                You found nothing while walking through the streets
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php?action=walk'><b>[Continue Traveling]</b></a>
            </td>
            <td align='center' width='50%'>
                <a href='streets.php'><b>[Back]</b></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";


  }

 }
while ($ir['steps'] > 0);
}
$h->endpage();
```

Comment: please only post the relevant code.

Comment: Please reduce your code significantly to only the issue you're facing and the code neccessary to reproduce it

Comment: So where is $ir['steps'] being changed in your loop? I can't see anywhere after wading through it

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE users SET crystals=crystals+$rewardtok,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");   

this is included for each result

Comment: I wouldn't say this question qualifies as being tagged by "JavaScript" or "HTML" because it contains HTML, nor as "Function" just because it's a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ir['steps']
```

is not changed/decremented anywhere.

Decrement it before at the end of the loop:

```
$ir['steps'] -= 1;
```

Just before the closing bracket of the loop.

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE users SET crystals=crystals+$rewardtok,steps=steps-1 WHERE userid=$userid");

Comment: Yes, you are updating it in the database, but not in the php loop itself. You should do the same thing in the loop as in the database. If you change data in the database, PHP will not be aware of the change on it's own. You should write the code to do so.

Comment: ohh im sorry im new at this. how would i do that?

Comment: Just accept the answer if it works, glad i was able to help you.